# Allowing the terminal to write Arabic

Tags: linux, terminal, arabic, right-to-left

How can allow the terminal on Linux to write Arabic without reversing its words?

For example, when I write "زمالك" it is written from left to right. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

It's a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vte/+bug/263822). Check out [mlterm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/mlterm.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the following packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libfribidi0 libfribidi-dev
   ```
2. Download & install [bicon](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebehnam/+archive/ppa/+build/574785/+files/bicon_0.2.0-1ubuntu0%7Eppa4_i386.deb).
3. Open `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop` in any editor you like:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
   ```
4. Add the following lines to the end of the file:

   ```
   Terminal=true
   Exec=/usr/bin/bicon.bin
   ```
5. If you have a terminal icon on your desktop, remove it and make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

GNOME Terminal version 3.34 supports right to left scripts such as Arabic, and so do other VTE-based emulators (e.g. Tilix, Terminator, Xfce Terminal, Guake...) if using VTE version 0.58.